# How to return a single object that was created with LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

I have a XML file that contains weather forecast data. I'm trying to query it via an XDocument. I have a class named "Forecast" and I'm trying to create an object of this type and populate it's properties with LINQ, like this:

```
public Forecast CurrentConditions(string stateName, string cityName)
{
    var data = from i in weatherResponse.Descendants("current_observation")
               select new Forecast
               {
                   TemperatureC = Convert.ToDouble(i.Element("temp_c").Value)
                   //Setting other properties here
               };

    return data;
}
```

My "Forecast" class contains only properties like this:

```
class Forecast
{
    public double TemperatureF { get; set; }
    public double TemperatureC { get; set; }
    public string RelativeHumidity { get; set; }
}
```

However VS highlights `return data;` and says `"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WeatherUnderground1.Forecast>' to 'WeatherUnderground1.Forecast'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"`

So if I change it to:

```
return (Forecast)data;
```

I get the exception "Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

**Question**

What am I doing wrong, and what is the correct way of returning the `Forecast` object?

Comment: try `return data.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Use this for getting the value instead `TemperatureC = (double)i.Element("temp_c")`

Answer (score 1):

The `select` is returning an `IEnumerable<Forecast>`, in other words a series of then, not a single one. If you know for certain there is only one, you can use,

```
public Forecast CurrentConditions(string stateName, string cityName)
{
    var datas = from i in weatherResponse.Descendants("current_observation")
               select new Forecast
               {
                   TemperatureC = Convert.ToDouble(i.Element("temp_c").Value)
                   //Setting other properties here
               };

    return datas.SingleOrDefault(); // Or FirstOrDefault() or LastOrDefault()
}
```

However, this will return `null` if there are more than one; this is probably what you want in case you need to do some sort of average among the several forecasts. You can use `datas.Count()` to know how many items are returned and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your query isn't selecting a single Forecast. If you want just the first one in the list, you could use `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
return data.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns an `IEnumerable<Forecast>`. You either want to return that, or
you need to append FirstOrDefault() or SingleOrDefault() to your query to return a single item.

```
public Forecast CurrentConditions(string stateName, string cityName)
{
    var data = from i in weatherResponse.Descendants("current_observation")
       select new Forecast
       {
           TemperatureC = Convert.ToDouble(i.Element("temp_c").Value)
           //Setting other properties here
       };

    //change this: return data;
    //to:
    return data.FirstOrDefault();
    //or (if you know for certain there can be no more than 1 item):
    return data.SingleOrDefault();
}
```